# National Instruments USB 6008 and Linux

Tags: php, python, octave, nidaqmx

I went to see if there was a data acquisition tool box for the program octave here but couldn't find one http://octave.sourceforge.net/packages.php

What I'm trying to do is use my National Instruments USB-6008 to acquire data in octave or any other program.  I would like to be able to export data to a text file in the format of 
year,month,day,hour,minute,second,voltage.

so the text file would take a reading every second and the text file will have the following data inside it
11182011054735,3.3V
11182011054736,3.9V
11182011054737,3.1V

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 Linux 64bit and a 32bit version for testing in a virtual box
Can Octave do this? Are there any examples or can someone recommend something else if octave can't do this?

PS:  I know matlab can do this but it's way to expensive for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [NI-DAQmx compatibility page](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/6913) it looks like your device works with [NI-DAQmx Base 3.4](http://joule.ni.com/nidu/cds/view/p/id/2127) in Linux.  So you could use its C API and build new functions, looks like [the wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/wiki.pl?CategoryExternal) has a few places to start.

Comment: Unfortunately ubuntu isn't supported, I've installed opensuse 11.3 and scientific linux 5.x in virtual box but the drivers they give out are extremely buggy, and have piss poor instructions.  People have complained about it, But it Looks like NI focus is on Windows platforms and everything else is secondary. I was hoping someone had a http://www.comedi.org/ type of driver but nothing as of yet

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit late, but here you have the step-by-step instructions for installing and compiling C programs with DAQmx Base in a 32 or 64bit Linux distro:

http://www.mrpt.org/NI_DAQmx_Base_in_openSUSE_64bit